# SqlDataReader.Read() always false in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have a Table in my local database `Ships(HistID,ShipName,ShipLength)`. I am polling the database for all ships with `HistID == theme`, but `while(reader.Read()){}` is never entered. Also, my Ships table has more than one row (saw this problem in another SO question) so I'm not sure why I cant store the results into List of Tuples. Executing the query alone in Visual Studio 2015 yields the correct results.

```
     public List<Tuple<String, int>> getHistoricalShipList(int theme)
        {
            List<Tuple<String, int>> list = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();

            using (db)
            {
                   cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Select ShipName, ShipLength from Ships Where HistID=@theme", db);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theme", theme);

                db.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows) // always returning false
                {
                    //Loop through results
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        String shipName = reader[0].ToString();
                        int shipLength = Convert.ToInt32(reader[1]);
                        list.Add(Tuple.Create(shipName, shipLength));
                    }
                }
                db.Close();
            }

            return list;
        }
```

EDIT:: removed the single quotes from the query as suggested, but still having the same issue.

Comment: What is the type of `HistID` column? Sounds like numeral based on it's name. You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by the way. This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: There is so many things going on in your code, that I don't know where to start. Check your using blocks. You have not enough and at least the one for db looks fishy. You should use parameters instead of string format for your query. And there is no point in having an if(hasRows) when you have a while loop around your read.

Comment: Use parametrized query, not string.Format. Does the generated query return any results outside your program?

Comment: Yes Vojtech, When I open up a Query editor in VS, the query returns what I need it to return. I am beginner, please excuse my terrible coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove HasRows check and just use the .Read while loop; there's various bug reports on HasRows not being entirely accurate in some cases.

Other than that, it's likely you're making a mistake somewhere. Either `theme` isn't what you expect it to be, or some environment error like hitting the wrong database.

Comment: I hate it when I blunder this bad. Theme was being passed in as 0 always, which doesn't exist in my DB. I hard-coded a 1 in (which exists) and the problem is solved. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 3):

Your `theme` is of type `int`, and you are enclosing it in single quotes like it is a string value. Remove the quotes, but **more importantly, use Parameters**

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format(@"Select ShipName, ShipLength from Ships Where HistID={0}", theme), db);
```

Never use string concatenation/string format to build SQL statements, your code is prone to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Select ShipName, ShipLength from Ships Where HistID=@theme", db);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theme", theme);
//Or more precise 
//cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@theme", SqlDbType.Int) {Value = theme});
```

The reason you are not getting any rows back is, that your field `HistID` is of numeric type and you are trying to compare it with a string value *(by enclosing the value in single quote)*.

Comment: `AddWithValue`? Ouchh.. :)

Comment: Oh no! Your right, I missed that. However, I updated that line and I'm still reader.Read() is still false. Updated OP with your correction.

Comment: Agreed w/everything except that this is the OP's actual problem; because of implicit conversion, the query would still work.

Comment: @SonerGönül There is nothing wrong with `AddWithValue` if you are using it on a non variable length or non ambiguous type. Sure, for strings and `byte[]` I would never use it, but for a int, there is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes, this isn't a problem in this case but as a general recommendation, specially explicitly specifying `DbType`, makes code much more readable and understandable in my opinion.